# Getting syntax error for the constructed xpath while executing script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

When I am searching for elements in the page itself using constructed `xpath`, it's highlighting 60 elements matching. But when I am trying to execute the same in script, it is throwing syntax error for the constructed `xpath`.

**Note : I used class attribute for constructing xpath having value "s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom s-latency-cf-section".**

Sharing some screenshots below for reference :

syntax error:
[image: syntax error]

Elements matching:
[image: Elements matching]

Comment: You’re using unescaped double quotes within a string literal enclosed in double quotes.  Change the quotes inside the XPath expression to single quotes.

Comment: @DavidDenenberg you should make that an answer, not a comment.